# Left Join table only if another join passes some criteria

Tags: sql, join, left-join, ssms

This is a SQL issue I run into all the time! (I use Sql-Server/sql-management studio) I want to left join a table but ONLY if it passes a test that requires another join. So I'm joining B onto A but I only want to join B if B's Join onto table C passes a test...

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.BID = B.BID  --only want to join B if C passes the test
LEFT JOIN TableC C on B.CID = C.CID
WHERE C.PassesTest -- not correct: throws out records from A that don't pass test
```

So I only want to left join B if C passes a test. As in my title, I basically want to left join 2 tables that are inner joined... "A left join (b inner join c) on C.PassesTest" is essentially what I want to do.

My 2 immediate thoughts BOTH FAIL:
1. If you put the PassesTest in the join to C, (... left join c on B.CID = C.CID AND C.PassesTest...) you still have all the B records hanging around that you don't want. 
2. If you put the test in the where (like above), it throws out all the A records that don't pass but I want those (as it's a left join).

I can think of 2 solutions but they're both a bit of a pain... Is there really no easier way of doing this???

1. join on all of B/C - this is logically what I want but obviously not optimal as it is grabbing EVERYTHING from B and C before the join (so it's slow)

   ```
   SELECT A.* 
   FROM TableA A
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT * 
     FROM TableB B 
     INNER JOIN TableC C ON B.CID = C.CID 
     WHERE C.PassesTest
   ) BC ON BC.BID = A.BID
   ```
2. Do some kind of nested select. The way below seems a little redundant... Maybe it can be written a little better

   ```
   SELECT ABC.StuffFromA FROM (
     SELECT * 
     FROM TableA A
     LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.BID = B.BID
     LEFT JOIN TableC C ON B.CID = C.CID 
   ) ABC
   LEFT JOIN TableB B on ABC.BID = B.BID AND ABC.PassesTest
   ```

Regardless, this is something I run into all the time and I always find myself having to do something excessively difficult to get it to work! It just seems like there should be an easier solution... Or is this just a deceptively difficult SQL problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `version 1` doesn't need to be a sub query, you just need `()` around the `INNER JOIN` section...

```
SELECT
  A.* 
FROM
  TableA A
LEFT JOIN
  (
    TableB B 
  INNER JOIN
    TableC C
      ON  B.CID = C.CID 
      AND C.PassesTest
  )
    ON B.BID = A.BID
```

I've also put what you have as a `WHERE` clause in the `INNER JOIN` predicate.

Also, be aware that in neither your sub-query version nor this example, does the entire of TableB necessarily get joined to TableC ***before*** being joined to TableA.

SQL is compiled to an execution plan, and the optimiser has many options to prevent this from happening.  Just because you have it written like that doesn't mean that the RDBMS will follow it blindly without optimising.

Comment: Awesome! I did not know you could do that! Thanks a bunch :)